# CNAME Issue with Custom Domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cname

I'm having an issue re-directing my domain locatious.herokuapp.com to locatious.com

For https://www.dropbox.com/s/61hkmokgxcdrsxu/Screenshot%202014-08-20%2023.28.40.png, I see the following error: Heroku | No Such App

For https://www.dropbox.com/s/o3k9frqud4t8sd3/Screenshot%202014-08-20%2023.31.02.png, I see another error: Application Error

My host, NameCheap, advised me that CNAME was correctly created from our end.

Inside the app, I also updated ApplicationController to be:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

before_filter :ensure_domain

APP_DOMAIN = 'www.locatious.com'

def ensure_domain
  if request.env['HTTP_HOST'] != APP_DOMAIN
  # HTTP 301 is a "permanent" redirect
  redirect_to "http://#{APP_DOMAIN}", :status => 301
end
```

NameCheap says the issue is on Heroku side. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CNAME**

We've used custom domains on [Heroku](http://heroku.com) before - the bottom line is that a CNAME reference is literally just a way to "redirect" a domain request to another domain, masking the redirection under the first domain.

The setup is relatively simple - just create a `CNAME` reference from the "new" domain you wish to use, and point it to your Heroku domain. Pretty simple stuff - *it looks like you have done this already & have it working!*:

[image]

---

**Errors**

After accessing your app from both your Heroku & "native" URL, I have come up with the same error both times

The error you're seeing is a *Heroku* error - this means that you've got a problem at *platform* level. The best way to describe this is that there are two types of errors with Rails apps on the Heroku platform -- "Rails" errors & "Heroku / Platform" errors

Rails:

[image]

Heroku:

[image]

The difference is that if you have a *Rails* error, it is a problem with your code / app. If you have a *Heroku* error, you have a problem with the platform itself (typically a database / dependency issue)

---

**Fix**

Your problem is undoubtedly one with Heroku

The issue I would recommend is that you have not got a database properly loaded - preventing Rails from firing up. If this is the case, you need to check your logs by using the CLI:

```
$ heroku logs
```

This will indicate the actual issue, allowing you to fix it. In all probability, it's most likely a **database** issue (either connectivity or populated)

Comment: Thanks Rich. After running `heroku logs`, I determined that the issue was: `H70 - Access to Bamboo HTTP endpoint denied`. I asked NameCheap to update my CNAME record from `locatious.heroku.com` to `locatious.herokuapp.com` and the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to use custom domain on heroku is what they suggest.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

I used that in the past and worked very well. Give it a try.

First remove your "ensure_domain" method. Make sure locatious.herokuapp.com works, then add custom domain.